# Site-to-Site Group policy

Tags: domain-name-system, group-policy, domain-controller, site-to-site-vpn, mappeddrive

So I have **Site A** and **Site B**.

At **Site A** is  a Domain Controller that has a OU called "GPO_test"

I have a GPO that maps a drive to **\\Server\Share** and given the drive letter **X:** linked to **GPO_test**

Now on **site A** everything works fine. But on **site B**, no one is getting hit by the GPO.

How can I make the GPO hit users on **site B** ?

**Additional information:**

Site A and B have **ZyWALL USG** firewalls running a **Site-to-Site VPN**.

**Site A** ip address range is 192.168.101.0/24

**Site B** ip address range is 192.168.102.0/24

Site B has the firewall DNS pointing to the DNS server on site A so they can resolve names (such as \\Server\Share)

Answer (score 0):

If you have linked the GPO directly to the OU the GPO should be execute no regards about client site connection.

In order to be sure lunch a GPResult from a client in SiteB and see if you see the GPO.

Check if you are be able to manual map the driver from SiteB, if this don't work the issue is in the VPN connection.

Comment: I will try and do a GPResult.

The VPN is fine, and I can without issues map to drives on site A

Comment: Did you see the affected GPO in  GPOresult?

Comment: I am getting long login times and there seem to be missing configurations from the GPO's. But I see some